# Review bar prevents me from editing posts in low quality queue

Tags: bug, review, edits, design

The issue is caused by the review bar having fixed position when you scroll. I'm not sure what purpose does that "feature" serve.

[image: image description]

I am using ad-block for now, the panel is useless anyway, but somebody could probably fix it.

Comment: Ad-block plus rule: `stackoverflow.com##.review-more-instructions.dno`

Comment: Have you tried clicking "(less)"?

Comment: No, but it's annoying even in the smaller form: